# single file webpage

Tags: cross-browser, html, mhtml

I'm trying to find a cross-browser capability for saving and loading entire webpages as single files. MHTML (.mht) is an example of such a file type, but it doesn't work cross-browser. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am assuming you don't want pdf?

Comment: just curious can you explain a bit more about why you want to do this, especially the saving/loading rationale?  There are **massive** caching benefits to *not* storing all your static content in the same file as your dynamic content... **massive**

Comment: @AhmedAeonAxan nope, don't want PDF

Comment: @scunliffe I'm making something that runs in a browser but isn't necessarily served by a server. Either I make users download an archive, unzip it and click on the main html file inside, or I use a handy format that can be clicked and opened in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

[grunt-inline](https://github.com/chyingp/grunt-inline) "Brings externally referenced resources, such as js, css and images, into a single file." and works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I need. It needs to allow for all of the web pages (HTML) in one file. I assume that if this is standardized then it will come in the form of an archive, like ePub or mhtml.